# Ignite.Net ScanQuery "Failed to inject resource"

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am trying the ScanQuery sample as given in: https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-apache-ignitenet-part-3-cache

I created an Ignite Server with Person class as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            // Register custom class for Ignite serialization
            BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person))
        };
        cfg.BinaryConfiguration.NameMapper = new BinaryBasicNameMapper() { IsSimpleName = true };

        IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
        ICache<int, Person> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>("persons");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inserting " + i + "th Person");
            cache.Put(i, new Person() { Name = "Person " + i, Age = (i + 1) * 10 });
        }

        Console.WriteLine("***** Ignite Server Started and Ready *****");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Person [Name={Name}, Age={Age}]";
    }
}
```

And a Thick Client as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            // Register custom class for Ignite serialization
            BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration(typeof(Person), typeof(PersonFilter))
        };
        cfg.ClientMode = true;
        cfg.BinaryConfiguration.NameMapper = new BinaryBasicNameMapper() { IsSimpleName = true };

        IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
        ICache<int, Person> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>("persons");

        //ScanQuery with Filter
        var scanQuery = new ScanQuery<int, Person>(new PersonFilter());
        IQueryCursor<ICacheEntry<int, Person>> queryCursor = cache.Query(scanQuery);
        foreach (ICacheEntry<int, Person> cacheEntry in queryCursor)
            Console.WriteLine(cacheEntry);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Person [Name={Name}, Age={Age}]";
    }
}

public class PersonFilter : ICacheEntryFilter<int, Person>
{
    public bool Invoke(ICacheEntry<int, Person> entry)
    {
        return entry.Key % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

When I run them both, the Thick Client throws error as:

JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to inject resource [method=setIgniteInstance, target=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCacheEntryFilterImpl@15b7b1c, rsrc=IgniteKernal [longJVMPauseDetector=LongJVMPauseDetector …

But this error goes away if I copy PersonFilter also in IgniteServer project and add it to the BinaryConfiguration types.

Is that how it is supposed to work? I thought Clients can create their own filters at runtime and run them against the server. Isn't that true? How would it work if the server is written in JAVA and client is in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `ScanQuery` requires filter implementation to be present on server side.

> How would it work if the server is written in JAVA and client is in .NET

This would not work, since Ignite needs to execute .NET filter on server side, and Java-only server node can't do that.

Comment: Thank you Pavel for the reply. So, are we essentially saying that anything with Filters (like ScanQuery or Continuous Query) will not work in Mixed-platform environment? Seems like a big drawback. Is there a workaround for such scenarios?

Comment: In short, is it even possible to have a filtered query which also listens on updates with Ignite running Java server and a .Net thick client? Any workaround will also be appreciated.

Comment: @Munni you are supposed to run .NET servers, is that an issue for you?

Comment: Yes Pavel, it has to be java and .net combination.

Comment: @Munni then run .NET Server nodes. Ignite.NET is built *on top* of Java, it is a superset.